# Некорректно работает inapp billing

Tags: java, android, google-play, in-app-purchases, android-billing

Не понимаю, почему inapp billing не может "употребить" покупку, гугл пишет что уже куплено, при этом isPurchased == false.

```
buy.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    if(billingProcessor.isPurchased("unlock_all"))
            billingProcessor.consumePurchase("unlock_all");

    billingProcessor.purchase(this,"unlock_all");
});
```

К тому же, после успешной покупки не срабатывает имплементированный метод проверки, зато метод ошибки работает

```
 @Override
public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
    Log.i("BP", "Purchased");
}
```

В onDestroy есть реализация, как советовал автор

```
   @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (billingProcessor != null)
        billingProcessor.release();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

И в onCreate его обычная инициализация

```
  billingProcessor = BillingProcessor.newBillingProcessor(this, "MY_KEY", this);
  billingProcessor.initialize();
```

Comment: Что за библиотеки вы используете? Ваш код выглядит как синхронный, хотя должен быть асинхронным. Вы используете Kotlin и Coroutines? Вроде нет... Возможно, вам надо некэшированные детали покупок сделанных получать.

Comment: вам нужно оф. клиент использовать, создать, потом подождать пока он соединится и т.п. см. оф. док.